# How do I see my sent SMS messages?

Tags: sms, htc-desire-hd

How do I see my sent SMS messages? I can search my text messages, but it's not obvious how to simply see a list of my sent messages ordered by time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [SMS Composer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-composer/smsr.com.sc) - it has non-threaded Inbox and sent message views which I believe is what you're looking for.

Also, it's freeware.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to use something like [SMS Backup+](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/com.zegoggles.smssync) which syncs your SMS and MMS messages to a particular tag in Gmail. You could then use normal gmail filtering to see your outgoing messages.